# Matriz bidimensional de números enteros

Tags: java

Matriz Bidimensional

```
import java.util.Scanner;
        public class MatrizNumeros {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

                int [] [] arreglo = new int [4] [5];
                int fil, col;

                for (fil = 0; fil < 4 ; fil++){
                    for (col = 0; col < 5 ; col++){
                        System.out.print("Ingresar numero: ");
                        arreglo[fil]= teclado.nextInt();

                    }
                }   
                    for (fil = 0; fil < 4 ; fil++){
                        for (col = 0; col < 5 ; col++){
                            System.out.print(fil, col);
                        }
                }

            }

        }
```

Necesito leer numeros enteros para una matriz de cuatro filas y cinco columnas y además que los imprima. Por favor si me pueden ayudar...

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema que tenes?

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con el código que incluyes en tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podes hacer es esto amigo, solo para que copies, pegues y verifiques:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrizNumeros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

    int[][] arreglo = new int [4][5];
    int fil, col;

    for(fil = 0; fil < 4; fil++ ){
      for(col = 0; col < 5; col++ ){
        System.out.print("Digite el numero ["+fil+"]["+col+"]: ");
        arreglo[fil][col] = teclado.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }

    for(fil = 0; fil < 4; fil++ ){
      for(col = 0; col < 5; col++ ){
        System.out.print(arreglo[fil][col]+"");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

**ERRORES:**
Estas pidiendo mal los datos de la matriz, en el primer bloque de fors solamente pones como indice de la matriz las filas del mismo, es decir, se tienen que pedir tanto las filas como las columnas de esta manera **arreglo[fil][col]**. De ese mismo modo vas a mostrar la matriz. **Abajo las explicaciones.**

**Primer bloque de fors:**
Lo que pasa acá es que pedimos todos los números del arreglo en el primer bloque de fors y si te fijas, en ese primer bloque, para que la entrada de datos sea mas ordenada, coloque un System.out.println("") para que una vez que pidas un número, haga un salto de línea.

**Segundo bloque de fors**
Aquí solamente mostramos el array "ordenadamente", aplicando el mismo salto de linea que en el primer for, para que una vez que se complete una fila el programa haga una tabulación y se comience la otra fila.

Answer (score 0):

En la sentencia for de tu codigo, al momento de insertar los valores que ingresa el usuario a tu matriz bidimensional, le estas diciendo que agregue el valor a la fila "fill". Ahora, como sabe a que columna lo tiene que agregar? Recorda que estamos en una matriz BIDIMENSIONAL, por lo cual al insertar cualquier valor, necesitas indicar fila y columna (como el codigo de abajo).

```
for (fil = 0; fil < 4 ; fil++){
    for (col = 0; col < 5 ; col++){
          System.out.print("Ingresar numero: ");
          arreglo[fil][col]= teclado.nextInt();
     }
 }
```

Tambien recorda, al momento de preguntar, de agregar siempre un mensaje del error, para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score -1):

a ver si te ayudo con este código;

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Matriz {

        public static final int 

ROWS = 4;
    public static final int COLS = 5;

    private int[][] matriz = new int [ROWS][COLS];

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Matriz() {

        for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
                System.out.print("Ingresar numero: ");
                matriz[i][j] = teclado.nextInt();
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param matriz
     */
    public void print(int[][] matriz) {

        for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the matriz
     */
    public int[][] getMatriz() {
        return matriz;
    }

    /**
     * @param matriz the matriz to set
     */
    public void setMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
        this.matriz = matriz;
    }

}

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Matriz matriz = new Matriz();
    matriz.print(matriz.getMatriz());
}

}
```

Comment: Este código no aporta una explicación para que el usuario entienda que estas realizando.